# why getting IndexError: string index out of range when i get no error when i print the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

i am getting error for 2 functions
where 2 functions are almost same.
in 1 function i just print and in another function i assign each word to a temp variable from list indices instead of printing. the function that prints gives no error but the function that assigns words instead of printing gives index out of bound error,why?
please check the_magic() and the_magic1() functions below :

```
def the_magic(str1,str2):
    str1 = str1
    str2 =  str2
    str3 = []

    for n in str1.split():
        for m in str2.split():
            if m in n:
                str3.append(n)
    if(len(str3)<1):
        str3 = ' '
    print(str3)
    for i  in range(len(str3)):
        print(str3[i])
    return str3

print(str3[i]) gives no error but ...

def the_magic1(str1,str2):
    str1 = str1
    str2 =  str2
    str3 = []

    for n in str1.split():
        for m in str2.split():
            if m in n:
                str3.append(n)
    if(len(str3)<1):
        str3 = ' '
    print(str3)
    for i  in range(len(str3)):
        temp = str3[i]
        if(temp == str2):
            str3 = str2
        else:
            str3 = str3[-1]
    return str3

temp = str3[i] giving error for the_magic1()
# function call :

a = "_MileyCyrus it wont let me do it twitter keeps saying over twitter capacity or something that bird keeps coming up."
b = 'it'
c = " "
b = b.split()
b = b[-1] 
str4=the_magic(a,b) # no error, returns str3 and  also prints each word
str4=the_magic1(a,b) #it gives error : IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: this code is full of not nessesary things - like: `str1=str1`, `str2=str2`, weird things like declaring `str3=[]` and later then `str3=' '`, assigning  `b='it'` and then splitting it and then assigning the last element of itself to it ... also text thats not code without commenting them in the code ...  Also whatever should the code do you are using in your methods? Whats the purpose? Please remove all the irrelevant stuff to make this a [mre] and explain what you are aiming at. thanks.

Comment: Why do you assign `str2` (a string) to `str3` (a list) inside your magic1 method? you change the content of str3 while iteating over its "former lenght as list" which makes no sense at all, sorry.

Comment: @MobassirHossen what does your **function the_magic1** should do because str3 list is being reassigned  with the values of str2 but the number of iteration remains same

Comment: `def meta_magic(word_list, text):` + `words_containing_text = [word for word in word_list.split() if text in word]' + 'print(*words_containing_text, sep="\n")` + `return words_containing_text`

Comment: it was for debugging purpose,,here is the updated code with solution provided by park : : https://pastebin.com/13KbaHFV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i  in list(str3):
        temp = i
        if(temp == str2):
            str3 = str2
        else:
            str3 = str3[-1]
    return str3
```

Comment: @HankPark It would be nice to replace `i` by `character` or `word` to make things more explicit. Also `temp` is not needed anymore!

Answer (score 0):

The functions are NOT doing the same.

```
# instead of printing you have:
    for i  in range(len(str3)):
        temp = str3[i]
        if(temp == str2):
            str3 = str2
        else:
            str3 = str3[-1]
# in the second function.
# problem is, as soon as first word in str3 - which is not a string
# but this list:
# ['it', 'it', 'twitter', 'twitter', 'capacity']
# so if you loop through the words and as soon as one word
# is identical to what is given by `b` (which is `it` in this example)
# str3 (the list) gets set to "it" (str2, here b).
# and if not, str3 gets set to the last word in the list.
# in both cases str3 is not a list any more.
```

You should explain what you intended to program with that.

#### Comments to your code

```
    str1 = str1
    str2 =  str2
    str3 = []
```

In Python, strings are always copied, so no need to fear `call by reference` problems when dealing with strings.
Simplify it to:

```
    str3 = []
```

```
    for n in str1.split():
        for m in str2.split():
            if m in n:
                str3.append(n)
```

Obviously you are searching which words in str1's words contain any of the words given in str2.
The rest is still not understandable.

Comment: it will give the same error now also because the looping is working on the length of str3 and if it is not a list anymore then it will throw an error

Comment: It was not meant as an correction but just showing what is happening in his code.